# add item to dropdownlistfor helper in asp.net mvc4(vb)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, dropdownlistfor

Please convert this code in asp.net mvc4 VB

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] 
{
new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString},
new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString}
}, "Choose an option")
```

when I write above C# code in VB like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.WillAttend, New SelectList( New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = "p"}, New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = "p"})
```

I got error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing this?  What attempt have you made and where are you stuck?

Comment: You can not order here to do something. Show us your effort

Comment: sir i edit my question and write what i tried to solve, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.WillAttend, New SelectListItem() {New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString}, New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString}}, "Choose an option")
```